# translation of assertion

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have been thinking about translating an assertions into a suitable formal logical language :" If they have vanilla, then I'll also have that, but otherwise I'll have chocolate." Since I am not sure what "But" really means, I tried two ways to translate it. V represents they have vanilla; C represents I'll have chocolate. The first way: (V-->V) and C. The second way: (V-->V) or (C and not V). Can anyone help me out? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. If "But" always means "and"? How about this assertion:"If we leave the window open, then water will get in, but only if it rains." If I apply the same reasoning, I would translate it as (O-->W) and (not W--> not R) – Deepsea234 9 hours ago   
     
I also think "but only if" as "if and only if" Therefore, O--> (W <--> R). Can anyone explain it more? Thanks. – Deepsea234

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, "but" is "and" with value judgement.

---

The natural language "but" is often used as a list-connective with an indication that the things being joined are of opposition in some sense.

"We have some bad news, *but* we have some good news too."   The news that is had is a union of bad news *and* good news.

---

More to the point, it is also used to *conjoin* conditionals with opposing antecedants (and *usually* disjoint consequences).   Such as in: "I will do this thing if I can, *but* I will do that thing if I can't."

So, "If they have vanilla, then I'll also have that, but otherwise I'll have chocolate," might be represented as: $$\big(H(t,v)~\to~ H(i,v)\big)~\wedge~\big(\neg H(t,v)~\to~ H(i,c)\big)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. If "But" always means "and"? How about this assertion:"If we leave the window open, then water will get in, but only if it rains." If I apply the same reasoning, I would translate it as (O-->W) and (not W--> not R)

Comment: I also think "but only if" as "if and only if" Therefore, O--> (W <--> R). Can anyone explain it more? Thanks.